# Exception Handling in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have seen a 1 appear at the end of eval blocks for exception handling in perl. Why is that required? What happens if an eval block returns false?

Is this required even if we dont use $@ directly but some library from CPAN to do exception handling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What happens if an eval block returns false?

That false value is returned by `eval`.

### Why is that required?

It's not required.

```
my $foo = eval { foo() };
```

is perfectly fine if you're ok with `$foo` being undef on exception.

What you've seen is

```
if (!eval { foo(); 1 }) {
   ...
}
```

The code is returning true to let the `if` know the `eval` succeeded. `eval` will return false on exception.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on ikegami's answer: most people write code like this:

```
eval { might_throw_exception() };
if ($@) { ... }
```

This is wrong pre-5.14, because `$@` may not be a true value even if an exception was thrown due to a destructor overwriting it, or other factors. `return 1` is a workaround; see [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.12/lib/Try/Tiny.pm#%24@_might_not_be_a_true_value) for a full explanation.

Comment: Not true.  This was an old bug that was fixed years ago now.  From the v5.14 delta: "When an exception is thrown inside an "eval", the exception is no longer at risk of being clobbered by destructor code running during unwinding."  There is a lot more than that; see the release notes.

Comment: @tchrist, Well, it's still possible by throwing an object that stringifies to "" or "0", but I must agree `if ($@)` is acceptable again now that the bug is fixed    ...assuming you're ok with throwing backwards compatibility out the window, that is.

Comment: I am aware of this fix and have updated my post. Regardless, a huge majority of Perl users are not using the more sensible Perl versions. CentOS 5 is still on 5.8!